# How to get input text value on click in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am learning ReactJS and I want to understand how to get the input text values in ReactJS using simple onclick event. I have followed there tutorial and although i am able to get the parameter of text input. But somehow i am not able to get its value. 
I know this is a dumb question, but i am struggling with this. 
Please check my code and let me know what's wrong with it.

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  handleClick: function() {
    if (this.refs.myInput !== null) {
        var input = this.refs.myInput;
            var inputValue = input.value;
      alert("Input is", inputValue);
    }
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref="myInput" />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Alert the text input"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here is jsfiddle for the same : [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/49490/)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

First of all, you can't pass to `alert` second argument, use concatenation instead

```
alert("Input is " + inputValue);
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/205071/)

However in order to get values from input better to use states like this

```js
var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return { input: '' };
  },

  handleChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({ input: e.target.value });
  },

  handleClick: function() {
    console.log(this.state.input);
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" onChange={ this.handleChange } />
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Alert the text input"
          onClick={this.handleClick}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Why should I update state for every change in input box? 
Shouldn't reading the value in input box on button click be easier?

Comment: What if my input is in separate component from my button?

Comment: @PrabhatDoongarwal I'm a total React noob, but I just came across this recommendation in the official react docs to use ["controlled components"](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) over ["uncontrolled components"](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html)

Answer (score 10):

There are two ways to go about doing this.

1. Create a state in the constructor that contains the text input. Attach an onChange event to the input box that updates state each time. Then onClick you could just alert the state object.
2. handleClick: function() {
       alert(this.refs.myInput.value);
     },

Comment: what is the best option in this case?

Answer (score 1):

**It is Simple:**

```
import {useState} from 'react';
 const[value, setValue] = useState(""); 
    function handle() {
        alert(value)
    }

<input value={value} onChange={(e) => {setValue(e.target.value)}} />
<button onClick={handle}>Button</button>
```