# how to get value of column in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-redux

I have table column like this which have value that comes from my reducer. the same column has increment/decrement button. so when use clicks on button I have to get value from that `<td>` and trigger my action. I am searching [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443227/how-to-get-input-text-value-on-click-in-reactjs) but its for input text which have event `onChange`. please anyone let me know how to do this?

Here is my `<td>` column:

```
<td>
    {this.props.prog}%
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" />
    </button>
    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">
        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" />
    </button>
</td>
```

**EDIT 1:**

I have tried something basically my onClick triggered properly but I am not able to pass the value

```
<td>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.props.resetGrowth}>Reset</button>
                        {this.props.prog}%
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick = {(event) => this.props.updated(this.props.prog) }>
                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up"/>
                        </button>
                        <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">
                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down"/>
                        </button>
                    </td>
```

it will pass to it this component

```
<Table updated={value => this.props.udated(value)}/>
```

this is my container it triggers value

```
 <VolumeComponent 
              udated = {(value) => updated(value)}/>

const mapDispatchToProps= (dispatch) => (
 bindActionCreators({updated},dispatch)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a reducer I am guessing you are using redux. If `{this.props.prog}`is your value, you could use this in the OnClick function you pass to the increase/ decrease buttons. For example:

```
handleDecrease(){
    const newValue = this.props.prog + 1;
    this.props.updateValue(newValue)
}

handleIncrease(){
    const newValue = this.props.prog - 1;
    this.props.updateValue(newValue)
}

render(){
    return (
        ...
        <button onClick={this.handleIncrease}/>
    );
}
```

Comment: yes it is redux can you please add an example. because values I am getting are from store

Comment: yes but I am not maintaining any state here. on load `componentdidmount` triggers an action which gives me value and I take values from `mapStateToProps`

Comment: When you are using redux you should try to avoid working with component states if not necessary. Instead you should add an updateValue (or how you want to call it) action, which updates the store.

Comment: `componenetdidmount` have written container not in components and  I don't have states anyhwere

Comment: what you require will add like that way?